Getting error while hitting HA Proxy frontend binding
I’m trying to run my scala service “Docker Image” using HA Proxy Data Plane API.
docker compose:
version: "3"

services:

  dataplaneapi:
    image: haproxytech/haproxy-ubuntu
    container_name: dataplaneapi
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy:rw
    command:
      - "/usr/local/bin/dataplaneapi"
      - "-f"
      - "/usr/local/etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml"
    networks:
      - my-network

  pekko-ha-proxy-container-1:
    container_name: pekko-ha-proxy-container-1
    image: pekko-ha-proxy:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "8090:8090"
    networks:
      - my-network

networks:
  my-network:
    external: true

haproxy.cfg:
# _md5hash=d3692304a2b0be4e094ffd4eb15f25b0
# _version=3
# Dataplaneapi managed File
# changing file directly can cause a conflict if dataplaneapi is running

global
  master-worker
  stats socket /var/run/haproxy.sock mode 660 level admin
  insecure-fork-wanted
  expose-deprecated-directives

userlist dataplaneapi
  user admin insecure-password adminpwd

frontend http
  mode http
  bind *:8100
  timeout client 10s
  stats enable
  stats uri /stats
  use_backend all

backend all
  mode http
  timeout server 50s
  timeout connect 50s
  server s1 pekko-ha-proxy-container-1:8090 check inter 5s fall 2 rise 2

program api
  command /usr/local/bin/dataplaneapi -f /etc/haproxy/dataplaneapi.yml
  no option start-on-reload

when I do $ docker compose up both containers go live.
I have checked frontend, backend and binding is fine via Data Plane API
$ curl -X GET   --user admin:adminpwd   "http://localhost:5555/v3/services/haproxy/configuration/frontends"
[{"client_timeout":10000,"mode":"http","name":"http","stats_options":{"stats_enable":true,"stats_show_node_name":null,"stats_uri_prefix":"/stats"}}]


$ curl -X GET   --user admin:adminpwd   "http://localhost:5555/v3/services/haproxy/configuration/backends"
[{"connect_timeout":50000,"mode":"http","name":"all","server_timeout":50000}]


$ curl -X GET   --user admin:adminpwd   "http://localhost:5555/v3/services/haproxy/configuration/frontends/http/binds"
[{"name":"*:8100","address":"*","port":8100}]

Now when I hit http://0.0.0.0:8100/hello via postman it is giving me Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:8100
Logs on container side are:
pekko-ha-proxy-container-1  | 2024-11-27 12:13:57.931 593 [main] PekkoHttpServer INFO - Server online at http://0.0.0.0:8090/
dataplaneapi                | time="2024-11-27T12:14:25Z" level=warning msg="Error setting up runtime client with socket: /var/run/haproxy.sock : cannot connect to runtime API /var/run/haproxy.sock within 30s: dial unix /var/run/haproxy.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
dataplaneapi                | time="2024-11-27T12:14:25Z" level=warning msg="Runtime API not configured, not using it: cannot connect to runtime API /var/run/haproxy.sock within 30s: dial unix /var/run/haproxy.sock: connect: no such file or directory"
dataplaneapi                | time="2024-11-27T12:14:26Z" level=info msg="Serving data plane at http://[::]:5555"

How can I resolve this issue and hit my scala service using HA Proxy Data Plane API?
